# Using multiple conditions in one if-statement in Ruby Language

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, if-statement, max

I write something like this in Ruby:

```
if a.max == a[0] 
  brand = b[0]
elsif a.max == a[1]
  brand = b[1]
elsif a.max == a[2]
  brand = b[2]
elsif a.max == a[3]
  brand = b[3]
end
```

`a` and `b` both are unique arrays.

Is there any way to check all `if` and `elsif`'s in the same condition?

Only one condition for `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[3]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-index) might help in cases like these (assuming the size of `a` and `b` is the same):

```
brand = b[a.index(a.max)]
```

In cases in which the array `a` might be empty, you will need an additional condition to avoid an error:

```
index = a.index(a.max)
brand = b[index] if index
```

Comment: and assuming that `a` is a unique Array of comparable objects so that `a.max` does not error out and cannot refer to more than 1 index (which can technically be inferred from the question)

Comment: I think non-uniqueness is not an issue here because my example would return the same result as the OP'S version even if the `a` contained duplicate elements.

Comment: Totally agree that your result is identical however the concern may still exist based purely on the naivety of the implementation

Comment: Yes a and b both are unique arrays. Index method works for me. Thanks :)))

Comment: How could `index` not be truthy?

Comment: `array.index(element)` would return `nil` if `element` is not included in `array`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Haha, that is true. I missed that. That makes my solution even simpler.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As long as `a` is not empty e.g. maybe add `unless a.empty?` because `a.max == a[0]` if `a` is empty but `b[nil]` will raise.

Answer (score 4):

Two more ways:

```
a = [3, 1, 6, 4]
b = [2, 8, 5, 7]
```

```
b[a.each_index.max_by { |i| a[i] }]
  #=> 5
```

or

```
b[a.each_with_index.max_by(&:first).last]
  #=> 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `a` and `b` have the same size, e.g.

```
a = [2, 5, 8, 1]
b = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

you could combine [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#zip-method) and [`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#max-method):

```
a.zip(b).max.last  # or more explicit: a.zip(b).max_by(&:first).last
#=> :c             # or reversed:      b.zip(a).max_by(&:last).first
```

or [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#max_by-method) and [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerator.html#with_index-method):

```
b.max_by.with_index { |_, i| a[i] }
#=> :c
```

Comment: The first example (non explicit version) will differ in result if the Arrays are `[1,2,4,4]` and `[:a,:b,:c,:d]`; however `a.zip(b).assoc(a.max).last` would work.

Answer (score 2):

If your array has multiple maxima, you may want to get the indices of the array that correspond to all the maxima:

```
a = [10, 12, 12]
b = [:a, :b, :c]

# Compute and store the maximum once, to avoid re-computing it in the
# loops below:
a_max = a.max

idxs = a.each_with_index.select{ |el, idx| el == a_max }.map{ |el, idx| idx }
# or:
idxs = a.each_with_index.map{ |el, idx| idx if el == a_max }.compact

puts "#{idxs}"
# [1, 2]

puts "#{idxs.map{ |idx| b[idx] }}"
# [:b, :c]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for the suggestion to compute `arr.max` only once, instead of for each element of array `a`. Added to the answer.

Comment: `puts "#{idxs.map{ |idx| b[idx] }}"` could also be written as `puts b.values_at(*idxs).inspect`