# If there's two maximum elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, max

In this code if user type 2, two times and 1, two times. Then there's two maximum elements and both Kinder and Twix should be printed. But how ? I probably can do this with if method but this will make my code even longer. Any cool version? Can I do this with just one if?

```
a = [0, 0, 0,]
b = ["Kinder", "Twix", "Mars"]

while true 
  input = gets.chomp.to_i
  if input == 1
    a[0] += 1
  elsif input == 2
    a[1] += 1
  elsif input == 3 
    a[2] += 1
  elsif input == 0 
    break
  end 
end

index = a.index(a.max)
chocolate = b[index] if index
print a.max,chocolate
```

Comment: I think what you're saying is `a = [2, 2, 0]`?

Comment: Yes, at the end of the loop a = [2, 2, 0]

Comment: Off-topic, but have you considered that using a hash instead of synchronized arrays would be more flexible and safer?  `popularity = Hash.new(0)` would create a hash where default values are zero, and then you could read *any* `name` and update the voting with `popularity[name] += 1`.

Comment: In Ruby instead of `while true` just do `loop do`.

Comment: Hint: `input > 0` and then `a[input - 1] += 1`

Comment: You had a solution in one of the answers to your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991796/967621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple conditions in one if-statement in Ruby Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991007/using-multiple-conditions-in-one-if-statement-in-ruby-language)

Comment: Hi pjs, thank you for your advice but I write this for my homework, and I need to work with what we learn. And hash is not one of them. Gonna use this for my next codes !

Comment: Timur, thank you for your solution but I want to see other methods actually. Yours is cool, but it's bit complicated for me. I was looking for something more simple to learn. I'm gonna try yours when I will learn the methods. :)

Comment: I added a second approach to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question really has nothing to do with how the array `a` is constructed.

```
def select_all_max(a, b)
  mx = a.max
  b.values_at(*a.each_index.select { |i| a[i] == mx })
end
```

```
b = ["Kinder", "Twix", "Mars"]
```

```
p select_all_max [0, 2, 1], b
["Twix"]

p select_all_max [2, 2, 1], b
["Kinder", "Twix"]
```

See [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

---

This could alternatively be done in a single pass.

```
def select_all_max(a, b)
  b.values_at(
    *(1..a.size-1).each_with_object([0]) do |i,arr|
      case a[i] <=> arr.last
      when 0
        arr << i
      when 1
        arr = [i]
      end
    end
  )
end
```

```
p select_all_max [0, 2, 1], b
["Twix"]

p select_all_max [2, 2, 1], b
["Kinder", "Twix"]

p select_all_max [1, 1, 1], b
["Kinder", "Twix", "Mars"]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be as follows:

First, just separate the input-gathering from the counting, so we'll just gather input in this step:

```
inputs = []
loop do
  input = gets.chomp.to_i
  break if input.zero?
  inputs << input 
end
```

Now we can tally up the inputs. If you have Ruby 2.7 you can simply do `counts_by_input = inputs.tally` to get `{ "Twix" => 2, "Kinder" => 2 }`. Otherwise, my preferred approach is to use [group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) with [transform_values](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/transform_values):

```
counts_by_input = inputs.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
# => { "Twix" => 2, "Kinder" => 2 }
```

Now, since we're going to be extracting values based on their count, we want to have the counts as keys. Normally we might [invert](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) the hash, but that won't work in this case because it will only give us one value per key, and we need multiple:

```
inputs_by_count = counts_by_input.invert
# => { 2 => "Kinder" }
# This doesn't work, it removed one of the values
```

Instead, we can use *another* `group_by` and `transform_values` (the reason I like these methods is because they're very versatile ...):

```
inputs_by_count = counts_by_input.
  group_by { |input, count| count }.
  transform_values { |keyvals| keyvals.map(&:first) }
# => { 2 => ["Twix", "Kinder"] }
```

The `transform_values` code here is probably a bit confusing, but one important thing to understand is that often times, calling [Enumerable](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable) methods on hashes converts them to `[[key1, val1], [key2, val2]]` arrays:

```
counts_by_input.group_by { |input, count| count }
# => { 2 => [["Twix", 2], ["Kinder", 2]] }
```

Which is why we call `transform_values { |keyvals| keyvals.map(&:first) }` afterwards to get our desired format `{ 2 => ["Twix", "Kinder"] }`

Anyway, at this point getting our result is very easy:

```
inputs_by_count[inputs_by_count.keys.max]
# => ["Twix", "Kinder"]
```

I know this probably all seems a little insane, but when you get familiar with Enumerable methods you will be able to do this kind of data transformation pretty fluently.

**Tl;dr, give me the codez**

```
inputs = []
loop do
  input = gets.chomp.to_i
  break if input.zero?
  inputs << input 
end

inputs_by_count = inputs.
  group_by(&:itself).
  transform_values(&:count).
  group_by { |keyvals, count| count }.
  transform_values { |keyvals| keyvals.map(&:first) }

top_count = inputs_by_count.keys.max
inputs_by_count[top_count]
# => ["Twix", "Kinder"]
```

Comment: It is really insane for me in this level but I'm gonna search this method. Thank you, that was really cool.

Comment: elixir, just take it a step at  time. Note `group_by(&:itself)` is shorthand for `group_by { |x| x }` and `transform_values(&:count)` is shorthand for `transform_values { |value| value.count }` and so on. `group_by { |keyvals, count| count }` can also be written `group_by(&:last)`. See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
maximum          = a.max # => 2
top_selling_bars = a.map.with_index { |e, i| b[i] if e == maximum }.compact # => ['Kinder', 'Twix']
p top_selling_bars # => ['Kinder', 'Twix']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
a = [2, 2, 0,]
b = ['Kinder', 'Twix', 'Mars']
```

You can calculate the maximum value in `a` via:

```
max = a.max #=> 2
```

and find all elements corresponding to that value via:

```
b.select.with_index { |_, i| a[i] == max }
#=> ["Kinder", "Twix"]
```